# What happened to Andy Fairweather Low and Greg Phillinganes regarding Eric Clapton?

Tags: rock, pop, bands, where-are-they-now

If you are also a fan of [Eric Clapton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Clapton), you've probably noticed like me that in the recent past (probably ten years) Eric almost has a new backup band for him apart from the great bassist [Nathan East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_East). I guess the two great supporting singers [Tessa Niles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessa_Niles) and [Katie Kissoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_and_Katie_Kissoon) are probably somehow in a retired-alike status and left the market.

But what about Eric's most frequent (?) second guitarist [Andy Fairweather Low](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Fairweather_Low) and the probably-not-so-frequent great keyboardist [Greg Phillinganes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Phillinganes)? Is there any problem between their relationship with Eric? It would be a huge pity to not see the best combination in my mind get together to do a gig. I wonder what happened?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the wikipedia articles [Andy Fairweather Low](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Fairweather_Low)  and [Greg Phillinganes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Phillinganes), they are both busy people, with lots of musical projects going on.  This is only my opinion, but it seems a more likely explanation for them not being in the current Clapton band than any "musical differences" between them and Clapton.